# why is tikzmarknode not recognized?

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,shapes.geometric}


\begin{document}


\tikzset{tikzmark prefix=ex5-}
Putting a node around \tikzmarknode{txt}{some text} means we can
connect text together, including in maths:
\[
\tikzmarknode{a}{\sum_{k=1}^n} k^{\tikzmarknode{b}{2}}
\]
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[->] (txt) -- (a);
\draw[->] (a.south) to[out=-90,in=-45] (b.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

I get Undefined control sequence for tikzmarknode.

Comment: Is your tex distribution up-to-date? Your example works without error for me with texlive2022  https://i.stack.imgur.com/tot4i.png

Comment: strange. indeed, when I upgraded my texlive, it seems to work. thank you.

Comment: You're welcome!